# Data virtualization in a WPF listbox

Tags: wpf, listbox, virtualization, listboxitems, data-virtualization

I have a scenario where in I populate a listbox with a 1000 items. I set the `ItemsSource` property with a source of data.

I have a requirement where I need to strike out an item of the listbox based on certain criteria, when the UI loads. I am using styles + attached properties to achieve the same by setting `ContentTemplate` of `ListBoxItem` in the callback method of attached property.

My problem is when I try to generate a `ListBoxItem` using `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem`, for an item which is at the end of the list, I get null. As a result, I cannot strike out items of the listbox which are at the bottom of the list.

Has it got something to do with virtualization. I want to obtain all those `ListBoxItems` on load.

Is there any workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely caused by virtualization. This is exactly what UI virtualization is supposed to do - only create `ListBoxItem` objects for items that are visible on the screen. You can easily see that this is indeed the cause by setting `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = false` on your `ListBox` and see that `ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem` no longer returns `null`.

You can set a style for your `ListBoxItems` in your `ListBox` that will have the logic to strike out the items as needed. This should also work when virtualization is enabled. For example:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType=ListBoxItem>
            ...
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```